# Creating users using the Microsoft Graph API (PHP)

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

#### Issue

I'm trying to build an app to integrate with the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

I have an admin account in Azure, and have set up a new app through the portal.
I've downloaded and installed the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php), and have managed to set everything up so that I can get a user successfully.

I can sign into the app and grant permissions to use my information (the permission I'm requesting is `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, but even just requesting `User.ReadWrite.All` is not working for me), however, my issue seems to be that I cannot access other users.

The following only returns my own user:

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken('/* SOMETOKEN */');
$users = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/users')
    ->setReturnType(User::class)
    ->execute();
```

POSTing a new user returns me a 404 error:

```
$newUser = new User();
$newUser->setAccountEnabled(true);
$newUser->setGivenName('first_name');
$newUser->setSurname('last_name');
$newUser->setUserPrincipalName('some.email@address.com');

$password = new PasswordProfile();
$password->setPassword('some_password');
$newUser->setPasswordProfile($password);

$user = $graph->createRequest('POST', '/users')
    ->attachBody($newUser)
    ->execute();
```

Returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://outlook.office365.com:444/profile/v1.0/users('CID:a8ef4446a149de4d')/profile?api-version=AGSV1-internal'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "/* timestamp */",
            "request-id": "/* an id */",
            "client-request-id": "/* an id */"
        }
    }
}
```

Even trying to use Microsoft's [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) is getting these same errors.

Am I right in thinking this could be an account setup issue?

#### Update

Here is the error message the Graph Explorer is returning

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://outlook.office365.com:444/profile/v1.0/users('CID:a8ef4446a149de4d')/profile?api-version=AGSV1-internal'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-30T16:51:41",
            "request-id": "743030b4-8835-4a9f-9e3e-d35919a1c289",
            "client-request-id": "c40cd440-d873-ba38-dce7-8669bc561e64"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide correlation id and timestamp

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity by "correlation ID", do you mean the request ID? If not, I'm not sure where to find that

Comment: Yes, please provide request id and timestamp in the error message

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I have updated the question to include this

Comment: Can you please check the token in jwt.ms you need to have a User.ReadWrite.All permission

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity as stated in the description, I have tried this with both the Directory.ReadWrite.All and User.ReadWrite.All permissions. Could it be possible that the API is not granting consent to these correctly?

Comment: Ben, You can't create "users" with an MSA, each account is a single user. You also cannot create a user in an AAD tenant without User.ReadWrite.All or Directory.ReadWrite.All permissions. Both of these will require content from a tenant administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this.

#### Issue

The issue was in the permission request.
My app was set up to allow personal accounts as well as work/school ones.
Logging in with a personal account, my user was not able to grant the `*.ReadWrite` or `*.All` permissions.

While I was getting a token back from the auth request, it only had the `User.Read` permission.

#### Steps needed to get access to all users working

1. Change the app in Azure to only accept work/school accounts
2. When my app tries to authenticate, I needed to log in with a work/school account
3. Granting the permissions for `User.Read.All` should now work
4. Hitting the `/users` endpoint should return all users

To get write working, I needed to [register for a Partner Center MPN ID](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/) and associate that with my app in Azure.